# Reflection of Lines in OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, math, geometry

I am trying to calculate the reflection of a line on a surface in OpenCV.

I work with a projectile im tracking which is drawing line 2 and a border.

I "just" want to draw a line of the bounce angle as you can see in my drawing.

[image: Skizze 1]

I got a code that calculate the angle of three given points but in my example line 2 is not static. It will move because its drawn by a moving projectile. So to calculate this i need the intersection point of the border and Line 2. Im kinda struggeling to get that..

Is there an easy way to solve this ?

Thank you.

Comment: how the line is defined? and the reflecting panel?

Comment: The line is Created by the Center of the Projectile and the predicted point of it by kalman filter:

`cv2.line(video,(center_x, center_y), (predicted2[0], predicted2[1]), (255, 255, 0), thickness=3) '`

and the  Border is an easy line. 

`    cv2.line(video,[200, 700],[900, 700],(0,0,255),thickness= 5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment:

Projectile coordinates (**P0**)

```
(center_x, center_y)
```

Impact point (**P1**)

```
(predicted2[0], predicted2[1])
```

Border extremes (**A, B**)

```
(Ax, Ay), (Bx, By)
```

I assume that P1 belongs to the segment AB.

You should project P0 in the straight line passing by A, B. Call this point PP. You should then compute

```
arctan(distance(PP,P1)/distance(P0,PP))
```

This is equal to alpha, that you can use to compute the reflection segment, depending on how long it is.

I suggest to use the shapely library:

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing that approach and the libary link